# Algorithms and methods for attribute/feature selection?

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, feature-selection

I have data with continuous class and I'm searching for good methods to reduce number of attributes. Now I'm using correlation based filters, random forests and Gram–Schmidt  algorithm.

What I want to achieve is answer which attributes are more important/relevant to class attribute than others.

By using methods that I mentioned before I can reach this goal, but is there any other good algorithms worth noticing?

Comment: Important or relevant to what??

Comment: Relevant to class attribute...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My heart will be always with RF, but still you may take a look at Rough Sets. Especially LERS works quite good in case of massively disturbed data.
You may also try with importance obtained from other classifiers, like SVMs or Random Naive Bayes.

Comment: Actually my data is rather small (~100 examples) and classifier is a result of using PCA (that's why it's continuous). Again can I use LERS, SVM or RNB with continuous classifier?

Comment: @pixel For SVM certainly (it is called SVM regression), for RNB there might not be an implementation, but it can be done as in RF. If not, and with LERS you may just partition the decision into a discrete groups -- it is a common trick and will be sufficient for feature selection.

Answer (score 6):

The [Task view on Machine Learning and Statistical Learning](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/MachineLearning.html) is a good starting point for question like this.

Answer (score 5):

Regularised regression with an L1 penatly term has worked well for me (c.f. LASSO and LARS).

Answer (score 5):

I'm a big fan of the [rfe](http://rgm2.lab.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/func.php?rd_id=caret%3arfe) function in the caret package.  You can easily use it to cross-validate feature importance ratings from a random forest, a linear model, a bagged-tree model, a naive bayesian model, or any other algorithm that returns a measure of variable importance.

You can [read more here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/vignettes/caretVarImp.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

I have had good results with ensemble feature selection procedures. For implementation you can take a look at the [Java-ML library](http://java-ml.sourceforge.net/).

For references see for example [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-87481-2_21).

I believe that these procedures are also readily availiable in R.

Answer (score 1):

[Principal Component Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) is a fairly common technique used to reduce the dimension of sampled data.  You can find a very good [implementation in R](http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/stats/html/prcomp.html).

Comment: Of course PCA reduces number of dimensions but also looses information about original attributes - it doesn't provide answer which attributes are 'better' than others.

Comment: In PCA you can look at the composition of components, so you can see what attributes were mainly used for creating first PCs. Nevertheless it is useless for data with complex or subtle dependencies.

Comment: Both comments are right. It is possible to weight which PCs encode more information by using the associated eigenvalues. However, PCA assumes that the information is encoded in the variance, which may be not true for all data sets.